# Разбивка строки на массив, содержащий подходящие и нет под regex строки, в их первичном порядке

Tags: javascript

Допустим есть строка `qwerty#1 2#.qwe#qwe 33#qwe_ty###23#dfg#q==w   qwertyuiop 
 #qwer`

С помощью данного регулярного выражения `/#[\wА-Яа-яЁё]{3,50}/g`

Регулярка ищет все подстроки начинающиеся с #, длиной от 3х до 50 символов (не включая #), которая может состоять из обоих регистров букв русского и латинского алфавитов и знака _

Я хочу получить следующий массив `['qwerty#1 2#.qwe', '#qwe', ' 33', '#qwe_ty', '###23', '#dfg', '#q==w   qwertyuiop  ', '#qwer']`

Как не пытался это сделать красиво, так и не смог, выходили большие и медленные костыли.

Comment: А так?: `/([^ ]+) +/ `

Comment: `"qwerty #qwerty qwertyuiop  #qwer".split(/\s+/)`

Comment: "qwerty #qwerty qwertyuiop  #qwer".split(' ');

Comment: Поздно про сплит вспомнил, сбился прочитав про регулярки =)

Comment: Там у предпоследнего элемента массива пробелы сохраняются, это так и задумано?

Comment: @bonusrk Да, именно так и задумано (не только у последнего, но ещё и у первого). Пробел, точка, не важно, будь это что угодно. Регулярка ищет все подстроки начинающиеся с # и чтобы после них была строка, длиной от 3х до 50 символов, возможно содержащая оба регистра букв русского и латинского алфавитов и знак _

Comment: Ох уж эти детали. Но в условии в результирующем массиве у первого элемента нет пробелов. И вот это вот новообретенное условие не объясняет что делать с пробелами после этих подстрок, и почему у предпоследнего элемента пробелы сохраняются.

Comment: @bonusrk Я обновил пример, надеюсь охватил возможные примеры, для лучшего понимания. Хотя на самом деле не столь важно как работает регулярка, она может быть любой, как и любой может быть строка.

Comment: `'qwerty#1 2#.qwe', ' 33'` — а по какой логике они в массиве? Если не начинаются с `#`...

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Вопрос прочтите, подходящие и не подходящие - все должны оказаться в результате в одном массиве, в порядке, в котором они находились в строке

Answer (score -2):

```js
const reg = /#[\wА-Яа-яЁё]{3,50}/g
const str = '#qwerty#1 2#.qwe#qwe#qwe 33#qwe_ty###23#dfg#q==w   qwertyuiop #qwer';
let last = 0;
let results = [];
const matches = str.matchAll(reg);

for (const match of matches) {
    results.push(str.slice(last, match.index));
    results.push(match[0]);
    last = match.index + match[0].length;
}
if (last < str.length) {
    results.push(str.slice(last));
}
results = results.filter(a => a) // Отсеиваем пустые строки
console.log(results)
```

Это всё, что Я хотел, сумел сам. Внимательнее читайте сам вопрос, его понимания достаточно для написания кода. Работает с другими строками и regexp.